# Firefox showing "connection not secure" for phpMyAdmin. Why do I not see the https:// in the URL?

Tags: security, https, phpmyadmin

I installed Apache server along with mysql, php and phpMyAdmin. Everything works fine. I am concerned about the security of the server. On the phpMyAdmin webpage, why does the `https://` not showing up ? Shouldn't it be like  `http://ip_address/phpMyAdmin/`
Also there comes a dialog box under the username box saying: `This connection is not secure. Logins entered here could be compromised.`

[image]

I am using openSUSE Leap 15.1
Any suggestions how to handle this, will be very helpful. I am new to this.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any certificates configured in your webserver? Also, do you plan to use phpMyAdmin remotely or only within an internal network?

Comment: @Shadow No I havn't configured any certificates in my webserver. I do not plan to use phpMyAdmin remotely, it is strictly for an internal network. I ran a 'mysql_secure_installation' and there I configured some security settings but, I suppose that is different and has nothing to do with this. I followed the steps given here: [https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:LAMP_setup]

Comment: This question has nothing to do with mysql, you are securing a http connection. You need a server-side certificate for that. If the data in mysql is not particularly sensitive, then on an internal network the lack of encryption is not a huge issue. However, this question has nothing to do with programming, you are trying to set up the admin environment and secure it. Serverfault or IT security sister sites can offer you help in such questions.